# Script to rename and copy files to a new directory.

Tags: python-3.x, python

Hi I have recently made this script to rename files I scan for work with a prefix and a date. It works pretty well however it would be great if it could make a directory in the current directory with the same name as the first file then move all the scanned files there. E.g. First file is renamed to 'Scanned As At 22-03-2012 0' then a directory called 'Scanned As At 22-03-2012 0' (Path being M:\Claire\Scanned As At 22-03-2012 0) is made and that file is placed in there.

I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to do this. Thanks in advance!

```
import os
import datetime
#target = input( 'Enter full directory path: ')
#prefix = input( 'Enter prefix: ')
target = 'M://Claire//'
prefix = 'Scanned As At '
os.chdir(target)
allfiles = os.listdir(target)
count = 0
for filename in allfiles:
    t = os.path.getmtime(filename)
    v = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)
    x = v.strftime( ' %d-%m-%Y')
    os.rename(filename, prefix + x + " "+str(count) +".pdf")
    count +=1
```

Comment: take a look at http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html

Comment: Where's the question?  Seems you know how to do it and have already done most of it.

Comment: Sorry I maybe should have been more clear. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to rename the folder with the same name format as the files and to actually make the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite clear about your requirement. If not rename the file, only put it under the directory, then you can use the following codes (only the for-loop of your example):

```
for filename in allfiles:
    if not os.isfile(filename): continue
    t = os.path.getmtime(filename)
    v = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)
    x = v.strftime( ' %d-%m-%Y')
    dirname = prefix + x + " " + str(count)
    target = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
    os.renames(filename, target)
    count +=1
```

You can check `help(os.renames)`.